# Not able to deploy to Websphere Application server 8.5 through Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, deployment, websphere

I am getting below error:
"No deployable artifacts found in path" while doing deploy through Jenkins.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Activation 0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ Activation ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ Activation ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:compile (default-compile) @ Activation ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\.jenkins\workspace\TestBuild\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ Activation ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ Activation ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ Activation ---
[JENKINS] Recording test results
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ Activation ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [Activation] in [C:\Users\.jenkins\workspace\TestBuild\target\Activation-0.1]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\.jenkins\workspace\TestBuild\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [462 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\.jenkins\workspace\TestBuild\target\Activation-0.1.war
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ Activation ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\.jenkins\workspace\TestBuild\target\Activation-0.1.war to C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\ibm\rest\Activation\0.1\Activation-0.1.war
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\.jenkins\workspace\TestBuild\pom.xml to    C:\Users\.m2\repository\com\ibm\rest\Activation\0.1\Activation-0.1.pom
    [JENKINS] Archiving disabled
    [JENKINS] Archiving disabled
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 8.926 s
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-17T15:19:38+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 23M/254M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    channel stopped
    Connecting to IBM WebSphere Application Server...
    No deployable artifacts found in path: C:\Users\.jenkins\workspace\modules/**lastSuccessful/**/Activation-*.ear
    Error deploying to IBM WebSphere Application Server: java.lang.Exception: No deployable artifacts found!
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.gatherArtifactPaths(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:286)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.websphere_deployer.WebSphereDeployerPlugin.perform(WebSphereDeployerPlugin.java:196)
        at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:744)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:690)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1073)
        at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:635)
        at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1749)
        at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:543)
        at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
        at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:421)
```

Below are my Jenkins Configurations:

[image]
[image]

[image]

Someone please suggest me what I am missing. I downloaded Maven Pluggin and Websphere Deploy Pluggin. My build is getting successful and also project is being copied in .jenkins/workplace folder but when it is trying to deploy to WAS , I am getting this error. Please guide me.

Comment: Looks like you're building a war but trying to deploy an ear.  Have you debugged that aspect?

Comment: tried that as well but no luck.Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Just use **/*.ear if you're only deploying 1 EAR file for the "EAR Path". It should find it. If you're deploying a WAR use **/*.war and it will generate the EAR for you.